# How to exclude admin from changes in WordPress php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to exclude admin from some changes to my site but not sure how to do it.

I have this php:

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 
'wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes', 9999 
);

function 
wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes()
{
global $wp_meta_boxes;
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'] = array();
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core'] = array();
}
```

This works to apply changes in general but to exclude admin I tried this and added it to the first php:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpso_add_admin_custom_css' ); 
function wpso_add_admin_custom_css() {
// Bail if Admin.
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    return;
}
```

So what's wrong with code:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpso_add_admin_custom_css' ); 
function wpso_add_admin_custom_css() {
// Bail if Admin.
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    return;
>? 

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 
'wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes', 9999 
);

function 
wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes()
{
global $wp_meta_boxes;
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'] = array();
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core'] = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_admin()` to only apply those actions to admin, or non-admin, requests. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

Eg:

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpso_add_admin_custom_css' );
    function wpso_add_admin_custom_css() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!is_admin()) {
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpso_add_admin_custom_css' );
    function wpso_add_admin_custom_css() {
        add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 
'wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes', 9999 
);

function 
wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes()
{
global $wp_meta_boxes;
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'] = array();
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core'] = array();
}
    }
}` like so?

Answer (score 0):

You can check user access with `current_user_can()` and bail if admin.

```
function wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'] = array();
    $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']   = array();
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes', 9999 );
```